# Remove stopwords while querying using GET Request in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, kibana-7

I'm trying to implement `Stop Token Filter` in an index of Elasticsearch. I've following code taken from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html#analysis-stop-tokenfilter).

```
PUT /test1
{
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
        "filter": {
            "my_stop": {
                "type":       "stop",
                "stopwords":  "_english_"
            }

        }
    }
}
}
```

I have my data stored in `JSON` format and have a field named as **Ingredients** which contains stopped words. I want to search through the whole index (containing almost 80k records) about the top 100 most appeared values in **Ingredients** tag. The query I'm using to retrieve the results is

```
GET test1/_search?size=0&pretty
{
"aggs": {
"genres": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "Ingredients",
    "size": 100,
    "exclude": "[0-9].*"
  }
}
}
}
```

I need to exclude Numbers from it for which I'm using `exclude`. 
But applying the above query using `Kibana` it doesn't remove the `Stop Words` and keeps them displayed while querying response.
As per the documentation, it should remove the stopped words but it isn't doing that. I'm unable to find the cause as I'm a newbie in `Elasticsearch`. Please help me figure it out.
I'm using `elasticsearch-7.3.1` and `Kibana-7.3.1`. 
 I'm working over it for about two days but none of the methods is working. Thanks! Any help would be really appreciated.

If I try it using this way, it works but while putting the `GET` request as per the method defined above, it doesn't work at all.

```
POST test1/_analyze
{
 "analyzer": "my_stop",
 "text": "House of Dickson<br> corp"
 }
```

**My Mapping**

```
    {
      "recipe_test" : {
"aliases" : { },
"mappings" : {
  "properties" : {
    "Author" : {
      "properties" : {
        "additionalInfo" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "description" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "eval" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "url" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "value" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Category" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Channel" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Cousine" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Ingredients" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      },
      "fielddata" : true
    },
    "Keywords" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "MakingMethod" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Publication" : {
      "properties" : {
        "additionalInfo" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "eval" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        },
        "published" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "url" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "value" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Rating" : {
      "properties" : {
        "bestRating" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "ratingCount" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "ratingValue" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "worstRating" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Servings" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "Timings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "cookTime" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "prepTime" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        },
        "totalTime" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "Title" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "description" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    },
    "recipe_url" : {
      "type" : "text",
      "fields" : {
        "keyword" : {
          "type" : "keyword",
          "ignore_above" : 256
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"settings" : {
  "index" : {
    "number_of_shards" : "1",
    "provided_name" : "recipe_test",
    "creation_date" : "1567443878756",
    "analysis" : {
      "filter" : {
        "english_stop" : {
          "type" : "stop",
          "stopwords" : "_english_"
        }
      },
      "analyzer" : {
        "rebuilt_stop" : {
          "filter" : [
            "asciifolding",
            "lowercase",
            "english_stop"
          ],
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        }
      }
    },
    "number_of_replicas" : "1",
    "uuid" : "K-FrOyc6QlWokGQoN6HxCg",
    "version" : {
      "created" : "7030199"
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

**My Example Data**

```
{
"recipe_url": "http1742637/bean-and-pesto-mash",
"Channel": "waqas",
 "recipe_id":"31",
"Title": "Bean & pesto mash",
"Rating": {
    "ratingValue": "4.625",
    "bestRating": "5",
    "worstRating": "1",
    "ratingCount": "8"
},
"Timings": {
    "cookTime": "PT5M",
    "prepTime": "PT5M",
    "totalTime": "PT10M"
},
"Author": {
    "eval": false,
    "value": "dfgkkdfgdfgfmes",
    "url": "https://www.example.com/",
    "additionalInfo": "Recipe from Good Food magazine, ",
    "description": "Substitute potatoes with pulses for a healthy alternative mash with a chunky texture",
    "published": "November 2011"
},
"Publication": {
    "eval": false,
    "value": "",
    "url": "",
    "additionalInfo": "",
    "published": ""
},
"Nutrition": "per serving",
"NutritionContents": {
    "kcal": "183",
    "fat": "5g",
    "saturates": "1g",
    "carbs": "25g",
    "sugars": "3g",
    "fibre": "7g",
    "protein": "11g",
    "salt": "0.84g"
},
"SkillLevel": "Easy",
"Ingredients": [
   "drizzle", "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" 

 ],
"MakingMethod": [
    "Heat the oil in a large saucepan. Add the beans and cook for 3-4 mins until hot through. Lightly mash with a potato masher for a chunky texture. Stir through the pesto and season. To serve, drizzle with a little olive oil, if you like."
],
"Keywords": [
    "Cannellini bean",
    "Cannellini beans",
    "Mash",
    "Beans",
    "Super healthy",
    "Pulses",
    "5-a-day",
    "Low fat",
    "Diet",
    "Dieting",
    "Side dish",
    "Bangers and mash",
    "Sausage and mash",
    "Texture",
    "Fireworks",
    "Pesto",
    "Easy",
    "Vegetarian",
    "Healthy",
    "Bonfire Night"
],
"Category": [
    "Side dish",
    "Dinner"
],
"Cousine": "British",
"Servings": "Serves 4"
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way on how to do this.

**Option 1**

Enable `fielddata` on the `text` field on which you applied the *correct* analyzer. Something like this:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "filter": {
        "english_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  "_english_" 
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "rebuilt_stop": {
          "filter": [
              "asciifolding",
              "lowercase",
              "english_stop"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "Ingredients": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "rebuilt_stop",
            "fielddata": true
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And then you run your `terms` aggregation.
Drawbacks: it could use [a lot of memory because of fielddata usage](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html).

**Option 2**

Use [term vectors API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/docs-termvectors.html). Since you are interested in the most used "values"/"terms" in `Ingredients` field you could call this API on one document in the index and have the total term frequency for each term in that specific document. The drawback: you need to specify a certain document ID and only the terms in that document will be reported back.

Something like this:

```
GET /test/_termvectors/1
{
  "fields" : ["Ingredients"],
  "offsets" : false,
  "payloads" : false,
  "positions" : false,
  "term_statistics" : true,
  "field_statistics" : false
}
```

**Option 3**

Probably the ugliest one. Something around these lines: [Elasticsearch: index a field with keyword tokenizer but without stopwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097075/elasticsearch-index-a-field-with-keyword-tokenizer-but-without-stopwords)

Advantage: is not using fielddata (heap memory). Drawback: you'd have to define the stopwords manually in the `char_filter` definition.

Comment: Please, post the exact mapping your index has (`GET /your_index_name`).

Comment: As I suspected: your `Ingredients` field doesn't have the analyzer set on it:`"Ingredients" : {      "type" : "text",      "fields" : {        "keyword" : {          "type" : "keyword",          "ignore_above" : 256        }      },      "fielddata" : true}`. Have a look at my mapping in the answer to see how the analyzer should be set in your index. You need to create a new index with the updated mapping, index the documents again and give it another try.

Comment: if I create the index after using your index, it's creating the same result as I've already posted. Do I need to perform any other task over it?

Comment: Then you must be doing something wrong... Have you tested my exact index? What sample data did you use?

Comment: What stopword was not removed?

Comment: or,and,of etc were not removed

Comment: I've added example data in the question. Please have a look

Comment: I don't see stopwords here: `"Ingredients": [
   "drizzle", "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" , "Asparagus" ]`

Comment: that's just a sample. I'm inserting data using `bulk api` and records are more than 80k